# Prooving that the residual semi-norm is a norm if and only if the subgroup is closed

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

So I want to proove a theorem I read in Vladimir Berkovich's "Spectral Theory and analytic geometry over non-achimedian fields".

The theorem is :
Let M be an abelian group, N a subgroup of M, and $\vert . \vert$ a semi-norm on M. The residue semi-norm is a norm if and only if N is closed

And a semi-norm $\vert.\vert : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$  is so that :

1. $\forall (a,b) \in M^2, \vert a-b \vert \leq \vert a \vert +\vert b \vert$
2. $\vert 0_M \vert = 0$

A norm is a semi-norm such that : $\vert a \vert=0 \implies a=0_M$

The residual semi-norm $\vert . \vert_{G/N}$ is such that :
$\vert\pi(a)\vert_{G/N}=$inf$ ( \vert u \vert, \pi(u)=\pi(a) )$

I managed to proove that the residual semi-norm is a semi-norm. I am now stuck on the theorem.

I began trying to proove that : If N is closed and $g \notin \pi^{-1}(N)$ then, $\vert \pi(g) \vert \neq 0$.
Appart from writing that $g$ is in $^cN$, which is open, so there is a ball of which $g$ is the center in $^cN$, I haven't been able to do much : I haven't found a thing to say about that ball.

I also tried ad absurdo but it didn't yeald.

Sorry for mistakes, english is not my first language. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Same proof as in the more usual particular case of normed vector spaces.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes! Thank you so much!